SDKManager not showing anything in Android Studio
I just installed android studio from "developer.android.com/studio" ( I`m trying to learn Kotlin )
I tried launching Android Studio normally and expected it to automatically download the necessary Android SDK files but instead I faced "No Android SDK found"
Also , not sure whether its related to my other problem but when i click "check for updates" i get "Connection failed (Request failed with status code 404). Please check network connection and try again" ( I know for a fact that my network connection is fine )
I have also tried both with and without a VPN but no difference
Arch Linux
Gnome 46
Android Studio Koala 2024.1.1 patch 2
Thank you in advance

This question is similar to: Android Studio Update Fails. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try to reinstall it sdk properly with good internet connection in one time some times partial downloading cause error in sdk , if not solved after that screenshot the error

Thank you sir for your answer , problem got fixed by using a dns ( for some reason I tried this same dns 3 times but it didnt work , it finally worked in the 4th time that i tried to use the dns )
